# How to set up two dask distributed schedulers on one machine?

Tags: python, dask

I want to have two dask distributed schedulers running on the same machine.

The second scheduler is meant for test purposes, and I was trying to start the scheduler and its workers by just calling `distributed.Client()` within an IPython notebook. However, if I do so, I can't figure out how to access the bokeh server of that second scheduler. Calling `scheduler_info()` indicates that the bokeh server might not be running.

How should I set up the two schedulers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Client()` without arguments is a convenient way to set up a local "cluster" on your personal machine for a short interactive session.  If you want to set up a dask scheduler in a more thorough way you might want to try either [dask.distributed.LocalCluster](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/local-cluster.html) or the `dask-scheduler` command line utility.  See documentation for [How to set up  a dask.distributed network](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html)

You can see the options available by passing `--help`

```
(py35) mrocklin@workstation:~$ dask-scheduler --help
Usage: dask-scheduler [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --port INTEGER                 Serving port
  --http-port INTEGER            HTTP port
  --bokeh-port INTEGER           Bokeh port
  --bokeh-internal-port INTEGER  Internal Bokeh port
  --bokeh / --no-bokeh           Launch Bokeh Web UI  [default: True]
  --host TEXT                    IP, hostname or URI of this server
  --show / --no-show             Show web UI
  --bokeh-whitelist TEXT         IP addresses to whitelist for bokeh.
  --prefix TEXT                  Prefix for the bokeh app
  --use-xheaders BOOLEAN         User xheaders in bokeh app for ssl
                                 termination in header  [default: False]
  --pid-file TEXT                File to write the process PID
  --scheduler-file TEXT          File to write connection information. This
                                 may be a good way to share connection
                                 information if your cluster is on a shared
                                 network file system.
  --help                         Show this message and exit.
```

To ensure that there aren't any conflicts between the two schedulers on the same machines you'll want to set the ports appropriately.

```
dask-scheduler --port XXXX --bokeh-port XXXX --bokeh-internal-port XXXX
```